# Symfony form shows up this error: This value is not valid

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Entity:

```
class Wheel {
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Car")
     */
    protected car;
    ...
}
```

Form:

```
class WheelType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        ....
        $form->add('car', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'namespace\Car',
        );
    ...
```

Controller:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
dump($form->getErrors(true));
exit;
```

Twig:

```
 {{ form_row(form.car) }}
```

Output:

```
FormErrorIterator {#1897 ▼
  -form: Form {#1861 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▼
    0 => FormError {#2083 ▼
      -message: "This value is not valid."
      #messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
        "{{ value }}" => "BMW"
      ]
      #messagePluralization: null
      -cause: ConstraintViolation {#2094 ▼
        -message: "This value is not valid."
        -messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
        -parameters: array:1 [▶]
        -plural: null
        -root: Form {#1861}
        -propertyPath: "children[car]"
        -invalidValue: "BMW"
        -constraint: Form {#1999 ▶}
        -code: 1
        -cause: TransformationFailedException {#1879 ▼
          #message: "Unable to reverse value for property path "car": The choice "BMW" does not exist or is not unique"
```

If I understood the error right, it says that it's unable to get the `doctrine` object from the `PK` **BMW**. Or **BMW** is unique and does exist for the entity `Car`.

Any ideas? Do I need to use data transformers? In which case it's very weird because this used to work in the previous symfony2 version (2.0)

Current version: symfony 2.7.6

Comment: It seems that transformers need to get used here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer which is very bizarre since it used to work before I upgrade my symfony to 2.7

Comment: you dont need that transformer if im not mistaking ?  you WOULD need that if for example, you allowed people to enter an id, or a name of  Car" in an input, but the way you are creating the form, the transformer should not be needed .   edit: just get rid of the transformer and try ...

Comment: @SamJanssens I'm not using a transformer

Comment: @smarber did you find a solution to this issue?